# Sharepoint Online - Doc Library on Site Collection pushed down to subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I have seen similar posts but not for SP Online, I have a doc library on the main site (doc library is called "Education - Shared Docs") and the customer would like a live copy of this doc library in each subsite so that no matter who is working on what it shows in everyone's team site Ed library.

OOTB suggestions?!

Comment: Do you mean a real copy or a view of the actual source documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could use SharePoint Desiner you can export the library view webpart (as List and library view pages are web part pages - they have “Edit Page” in the Site Actions menu"). After simple upload exported webpart to webparts gallery, and after add that webpart to every subsite like you add any other webparts (it will be in Custom webparts section).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Content Query webpart for this.The CQWP is part of the Publishing feature which is only available in the Enterprise plans and not in the Small Business plan.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a "copy" of the library in each sub-site, It would be a good approach to follow the below steps to keep things simple and OOB:

1. Give the link of the document library to users of sub-site
2. Give permissions to users on the library.